# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_IOException'

Tags: php, google-api-client

I am trying to make work a php code for listing the users of  a google user. I have followed a [youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SScwYK-te-g) and tryed the solutions proposed in [this one](http://25labs.com/tutorial-implementing-google-api-using-oauth-2-0-in-php/)  But I still get this annoying error when I call the authenticate method :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_IOException' with message 'HTTP Error: (0) couldn't connect to host' in D:\xampp\htdocs\yac\proxy\lib\google-api-client\io\Google_CurlIO.php:128 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\yac\proxy\lib\google-api-client\auth\Google_OAuth2.php(103): Google_CurlIO->makeRequest(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\yac\proxy\lib\google-api-client\Google_Client.php(131): Google_OAuth2->authenticate(Array, NULL) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\yac\proxy\contacts.php(36): Google_Client->authenticate() #3 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\yac\proxy\lib\google-api-client\io\Google_CurlIO.php on line 128
```

here is my PHP code :

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'lib/google-api-client/Google_Client.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Contactoos");
$client->setClientId('*************************************');
$client->setClientSecret('*********************************');
$client->setScopes(array('http://www.google.com/m8/feeds'));
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/yac/proxy/contacts.php');
$client->setAccessType('online');

if(isset($_GET['code']))
{
echo "here";
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('location:http://localhost/yac/proxy/contacts.php');
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
    $url = $client->createAuthUrl();

    ?>
    <a href="<?=$url;?>"> List google contacts</a>
    <?php
}
else
{
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

?>
```

As I said, I tried the solutions proposed in the second tutorial but in vain.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your server is having issues connecting to www.googleapis.com. You will need to check your network connection.

See if you're able to visit https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis from that machine.

If you are using a proxy then you need to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'your-proxy-settings');` to `Google_CurlIO.php`.

I've added it on *line 111*, after `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $request->getUserAgent());`

Comment: Indeed, that was the proxy. Thanks a lot.